# syntax error encountered in Window function implementation in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute the following implementation of window function

```
SELECT employee_no, employee_name, department_no, 
       round(avg(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY e.department_no),2) AS dept_avg_salary, 
       salary as salary_of_employee 
FROM employee e 
WHERE e.department_no is not null and salary > (select avg(salary) 
                from employee e2 
                where e2.department_no = e.department_no 
                groupby e2.department_no
               );
```

> Error 1064 encountered.

**Please help**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `over` is part of the `avg()`, not the `round()`.  So you need to express this as:

```
round(avg(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY e.department_no), 2)
```

Comment: same error persists. updated query as follows:

`SELECT employee_no, 
employee_name, 
department_no, 
round(avg(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY department_no),2) AS dept_avg_salary, 
salary as salary_of_employee 
FROM employee e 
WHERE e.department_no is not null and e.salary > (select avg(salary) from employee e2 where e2.department_no = e.department_no);`

Comment: @PranavSeth . .  In that case, perhaps you are using a pre-Mysql 8.0 version that doesn't support window functions.

Comment: @PranavSeth . . . Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Gordon has corrected the syntax error, so i would correct the subquery :

```
select avg(e2.salary) 
from employee e2 
where e2.department_no = e.department_no
```

You have already correlated the sub-query with outer query, so you don't need to use `GROUP BY`.

So, final `where` clause with `sub-query` will be :

```
WHERE e.salary > (select avg(e2.salary) 
                  from employee e2 
                  where e2.department_no = e.department_no 
                 );
```